# Need Help using a loop to perform a mass insert in SQL

Tags: sql

First off, i should say up front that i am not a very strong SQL person, so please be gentle :)

I need to perform about 400 inserts into a particular table.  The data that i will be using for these inserts, i can collect from a SELECT statement that runs off a different table.  I only need the data from 1 column from this table.

So, im hoping someone can help me write the SQL that will basically take the list of id's that are returned from my select, and use that list to do a mass insert into another table.

In psuedocode, something like this:

`Select BankID from BankTable;`  - this returns 300 rows

```
Insert Into AccountTable -- this will add all 300 rows into the 2nd table
Values
(BankID)
```

thanks in advance guys...

Answer (score 2):

Very simple, you basically said it. :-)

```
INSERT Into AccountTable (BankId, SecondColumn) SELECT BankId,'XXX' as staticText FROM BankTable;
```

Comment: hmmmm..what if the inserting table actually needs 2 columns (i didnt show that in the initial example in my attempt to keep it simple). For example, the insert would REALLY be (BANKID, 'XXX'). I'm using 'xxx' just to show that the 2nd field will be the same for each entry.. only the bankid is changing

Comment: People here are clever. Always post what you are trying to do, not an example of what you are trying to do :)

Comment: I updated my answer to fit what I think you're trying to do. I believe that is the syntax, but of course, I can't test it.

Comment: thanks guys.. the help is much appreciated.  PRESSING - i see you just updated your answer.  If this works i will be a very happy camper indeed.  I will try it in a bit and report what happens.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in one statement:

```
Insert Into AccountTable (bankid)
Select BankID from BankTable
```

This assumes that the column in `AccountTable` is also named `bankid`; if not, just set the name appropriately in the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind your INSERT statement must include the columns if the select statement does not match your table definition precisely.

```
INSERT AccountTable (BankID)
SELECT BankID
FROM BankTable
```

For multiple columns simply include the column list:

```
INSERT AccountTable (BankID, BankName)
SELECT BankID, BankName
FROM BankTable
```

You can also run into type conversion issues if the data types of the columns don't match (i.e. integer fields won't take alpha characters, etc.), but it is not a necessity that the column *names* match.  Just get the order of columns and types right and you should be good.

Comment: thanks tetch.. i think you guys have given me enough to give this a shot.  i'll probably mess something up and have some followups, but i think you guys have shown me what i need to do.. thanks all